# calling data from database to make calculation (PHP)

Tags: javascript, php

I have problem, I want to calculate summation of height and weight after height is updated. The problem is after I click update, height is updated however  weight will automatically change value to user_id (integer). So the summation will be bmi=height+id. Can you guys help solve my problem?

Below is PHP coding and form which I am using Bootstrap.

```js
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->
```

```
if(isset($_POST['updateH']))
{

    $height = $_POST['height'];

    $weight = $_SESSION['user'];

    $bmi = $height + $weight;

    $sql = "UPDATE users 
        SET 
        height = $height, 
        weight = $weight,
        bmi = $bmi, 
        WHERE user_id=" . $_SESSION['user']; 

    $result=mysql_query($sql); 

    // if successfully insert data into database, displays message "Successful". 
    if($result){ 
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Update Successfully!')</script>";
    }
    else 
    echo mysql_error();
}
```

```html
<form method="post" role="form">

  <h3> Height : <?php echo $userRow['height']; ?>&nbsp; cm</h3> 
  <input type="number" class="small" name="height" id="height" min="100" max="200" placeholder="Update Height CM"/>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" name="updateH"> UPDATE </button>

    </form>
```

Comment: Which value $_SESSION['user'] holds for ?

Comment: What is the weight supposed to be if not the user array key in your session? Odd naming if that is correct.

Comment: syira I think you need a break from the screen bud :>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have input field for Weight.
May be you are noticing it or maybe I'm wrong
Ok try this html code

```
<form method="post" role="form">
<h3> Height : <?php echo $userRow['height']; ?>&nbsp; cm</h3> 
  <input type="number" class="small" name="height" id="height" min="100" max="200" placeholder="Update Height CM"/>
  <input type="number" class="small" name="weight" id="height" min="10" max="200" placeholder="Update Weight CM"/>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" name="updateH"> UPDATE </button>

    </form>
```

And in javascript use the following

```
if(isset($_POST['updateH']))
{

    $height = $_POST['height'];

    $weight = $_POST['weight'];

    $bmi = $height + $weight;

    $sql = "UPDATE users SET height ='".$height."',weight ='".$weight."',bmi ='".$bmi."' WHERE user_id='".$_SESSION['user']."'"; 

    $result=mysql_query($sql); 

    // if successfully insert data into database, displays message "Successful". 
    if($result){ 
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Update Successfully!')</script>";
    }
    else 
    echo mysql_error();
}
```

Comment: as far as my doubt is please check the value of the weight before updating in the database. because `$_session['user']` will update the session variable of user id only. if you want to get the weight value from the database use select query to get it and after that do the calculation and then update it in the database

Comment: ohh okay i'll try then

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a format error in your sql statement
Use this

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET height ='".$height."',weight ='".$weight."',bmi ='".$bmi."' WHERE user_id='".$_SESSION['user']."'";
```

If it is not updated for the above query

call `mysql_commit();` after your `mysql_query();` statement

Let me know if it is helpful

Comment: i think we all think he has a problem with `$weight = $_SESSION['user'];`

Comment: Yes I also guess so @Drew But I have answered by assuming that this session variable has some value and he is doing something with that

Comment: I already changed my sql statement but is still have the same problem..and for mysql_commit() do you mean put it under $result=mysql_query($sql);  because I get error after doing that.

Comment: Yeah you should put `mysql_commit();` after the `$result=mysql_query($sql);` statement. If it is throwing the error then remove `mysql_commit();` and try with the above query

Comment: Yes, I already try but it gets the same problem..weight suddenly change to value of user_id

Comment: He is doing something with it @Rajeshkannan. He is using a session variable that contains his userId. Look at the names of what he is putting in it. It seems like such common sense to me, I could be wrong.

Comment: Yeah @syira because you are using the `$weight = $_SESSION['user'];` so it'll change your weight into user id only. If you don't want user_id atleast tell us what value you are expecting in place of weight

Comment: @Drew should I change user variable in $_SESSION['user'] instead?

Comment: this is what I think not having all your source code. You mean to say something like `$weight = $_POST['weight'];` if such a thing exists and only YOU would know that

Comment: that is, if the isset($_POST['height']) and isset($_POST['weight']) are accurate, ..., survive an if stmt

Comment: @drew I already try that before and the value is 0 while in my database there are value in my weight since I already can calculate BMI if user enter their weight and height..but for update I really lost

Comment: you are in good hands with Rajesh, he will take care of it if anyone can :>

Comment: @Rajeshkannan i already have value for weight (decimal) in the database. should I edit my post for my whole coding to make it clear?

Comment: ok if it is in database how you are getting it because using $_SESSION you can't get the database variable it'll return the session variable only.. better post your full code please